# Extract work items to an excel with more fields added to it

Tags: azure-devops

I am extracting the list of bugs from Azure Devops using Query. I was able to extract the bugs but it was extracted only with ID, Description, work item type and assigned to fields alone. I wanted to extract the list of bugs with some more fields like closed by, created by, raised by. I have explored custom setting but I could not able to get the desired result. Let me know if this is achievable in Azure Devops please.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DevOps portal, seems you could not export them to csv with these values.

You could export them and get the work item ids, then use the REST API - [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) in a loop, the API will return the values you want.

Please refer to the sample response here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#get-work-item